# how to run query and module in a form with a button-click in access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, module

i have two saved queries and one module, 
i want to let run These in a form with a button-click.

i tried a simple code successless:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute "q1"
CurrentDb.Execute "q2"
CurrentDb.Execute "modul1"
MsgBox ("finish!")




End Sub
```

could someone help me?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "q1"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "q2"
DoCmd.OpenModule "modul1"
```